# Significato di "attaccare secco a qualcuno"

Tags: meaning, regional

Nel racconto *Ferro* dal libro *Il sistema periodico*, di Primo Levi, ho letto questo passaggio riferito a Sandro, un amico piemontese  (e che si esprime con accento piemontese o in piemontese) dell'autore dei tempi in cui studiava chimica all'università (grassetto mio):

> D'inverno, quando **gli attaccava secco**, legava gli sci alla bicicletta rugginosa, partiva di buonora, e pedalava fino alla neve, senza soldi, con un carciofo in tasca e l’altra piena d’insalata: tornava poi a sera, o anche il giorno dopo, dormendo nei fienili, e piú tormenta e fame aveva patito, piú era contento e meglio stava di salute.

Non capisco il senso di "gli attaccava secco" in questo brano. Ho cercato alle voci "attaccare" e "secco" di parecchi dizionari, ma non sono riuscita a trovare questa espressione. Sapreste spiegarmi cosa significa?

Comment: "attaccare" viene usato secondo me nel senso di "iniziare"; "secco" potrebbe riferirsi ad una qualtià del tempo atmosferico dell'inverno (freddo secco ma non umido) oppure nel senso di "risoluto"  - da intendersi quindi una cosa del tipo "quando l'inverno iniziava a farsi sentire sul serio..." o simili

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si tratta di un'espressione derivata dal piemontese "ai tacàva sec", perfettamente calzante con la descrizione di Sandro. In italiano si potrebbe rendere con "gli prendevano i cinque minuti", per esprimere una voglia o un desiderio improvviso al quale non si riesce a rinunciare, anche a costo di fatica e sacrifici, proprio come quelli a cui si sottopone (con soddisfazione) il protagonista del racconto.

Comment: Ho trovato un riferimento a questa espressione nel libro [*Primo Levi e il piemontese. La lingua de «La chiave a stella»*](https://books.google.es/books?id=1sNUDwAAQBAJ&pg=source=bl&ots=f9liAUv8iZ&sig=ACfU3U1SRGh7Y89b5wvhqaj9ZQ9pAt92uQ&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiqm5jFqY7qAhWKHhQKHQQuAB0Q6AEwBnoECAgQAQ#q=%22attaccava%20secco%22&f=false), di [Bruno Villata](https://www.concordia.ca/artsci/cmll/faculty.html?fpid=bruno-villata),   che conferma il significato e l'origine piemontese.