# Significato e uso di "tirare l'ala"

Tags: word-usage, meaning, idioms, regional

Nel racconto *Ferro* dal libro *Il sistema periodico*, di Primo Levi, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> La facile cresta doveva bene essere facile, anzi elementare, d’estate, ma noi la trovammo in condizioni scomode. La roccia era bagnata sul versante al sole, e coperta di vetrato nero su quello in ombra; fra uno spuntone e l’altro c’erano sacche di neve fradicia dove si affondava fino alla cintura. Arrivammo in cima alle cinque, io **tirando l’ala** da far pena, Sandro in preda ad un’ilarità sinistra che io trovavo irritante.

Sapreste spiegarmi il significato dell'espressione "tirare l'ala" che appare nel testo?

Ho cercato alla voce "ala" di parecchi dizionari, incluso il dizionario dei modi di dire Hoepli, ma non ho trovato questa locuzione. Tuttavia, una ricerca su Google di "tirare l'ala" dà parecchie occorrenze.

Si tratta forse di un'espressione di origine e uso regionale come quella che appare in [questa domanda](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/12989/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Su Google Libri ho trovato il libro [*Primo Levi e il piemontese. La lingua de «La chiave a stella»*](https://books.google.es/books?id=1sNUDwAAQBAJ&pg=PR49&lpg=PR49&dq=%22tirare+l%27ala%22&source=bl&ots=f9liAUv8iZ&sig=ACfU3U1SRGh7Y89b5wvhqaj9ZQ9pAt92uQ&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiqm5jFqY7qAhWKHhQKHQQuAB0Q6AEwBnoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22tirare%20l%27ala%22&f=false), di [Bruno Villata](https://www.concordia.ca/artsci/cmll/faculty.html?fpid=bruno-villata),  in cui si fa un'analisi del linguaggio di un altro dei romanzi di Primo Levi.

Una delle sue sezioni fa un elenco di

> espressioni composte da parole italiane, le
> cui associazioni sono però tipicamente piemontesi

tra cui si trova appunto "tirare l'ala":

> **TIRARE L'ALA** 
> Ha il senso del piemontese **tiré l'ala**, cioè “ansare in salita" ("il committente che tirava un po' l'ala", p. 16; "il furgoncino tirava un po' l'ala", p. 130).

Quindi, si tratta di un'espressione di origine piemontese col significato di “ansare in salita", in questo caso salendo la cresta descritta nel passaggio, con tutte le difficoltà trovate dall'autore per arrivare in cima.

Comment: La fonte mi sembra sufficientemente autorevole come per poter accettare la risposta.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a common Italian expression but, given the context, it means something like "a fatica". Levi wants to point out that he had some difficulty in getting on top of the hill with that expression.

Comment: Benvenuto! Ecco una piccola informazione: su questo sito, di solito, [si risponde in italiano a una domanda in italiano](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6/).

Comment: Il problema che trovo in questa risposta è che cercare di indovinare il significato dal contesto è qualcosa che anch'io sono capace di fare.